# Previous next button inside bootstrap dynamic modal

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi am trying to create a team section based on the click of each team member I am showing a single bootstrap modal with the particular member details, I need help to add prev next button functionality  inside the modal using jquery, Here is js fiddle url https://jsfiddle.net/txkh3w16/2/

Test2
                      cm
                    
                  
                
                
                  
                    
                    
                      Tst-1
                      Deputy Prime Ministery

```
          <div class="modal fade" id="profileDetail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="profileDetail" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="profiledetail-head">
          <div class="profiledetail-head-inner">
            <div class="profiledetail-avatar"></div>
            <div class="profiledetail-name-desg">
              <h2 class="profiledetail-name"></h2>
              <div class="profiledetail-desg"></div>
            </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profiledetail-content">
          <span class="profile-title"></span>
          <span class="profile-content"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-controls">
          <div class="prev"> < prev</div>
          <div class="next">next > </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the updated fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/txkh3w16/5/

Basically you need to find out the next available card when user clicks on the next button, and the previous when user clicks previous. I am doing that by keeping track of the currently open `modal` in `openProfile` variable. On click of `.next` or `.prev`, you need to find out the applicable `.profile-card` and populate its content into the modal.

But as you click `.profile-card` the open modal is hidden due to `blur` event on it. So, you can open it back again using `$('#profileDetail').modal('show')`. But since the animation of modal hiding might be in progress, you'd need to wait for half a second to reopen the modal.

```
$(".next").click(function(event){
  var cards = openProfile.parents('.row').find(".profile-card");
  var currentCardIndex = cards.index(openProfile);
  if(cards.length > (currentCardIndex + 1)) {
    cards.get(currentCardIndex + 1).click();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#profileDetail").modal("show");
    },500);
  } else {
    alert("You are on the last card!");
  }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept my answer, to indicate that you have found the solution you need. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: accepted, one more doubt how can i add title of the profile as next and previous button

Comment: You could do that. In the click  handler for `profile-card` you'd need to find out whether there is a next/prev card or not. And find the title using `$(this).find('.profile-name').text()`, and set the label on the next/prev buttons using something like `$('.prev').text('new_label')`.